# IllegalArgumentException during ImageIO.read()

Tags: sprite, javax.imageio

I have an IllegalArgumentException and have no Idea how to fix it.

```
Exception in thread "Display" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.cube.zambezi.graphics.Sprite.<clinit>(Sprite.java:16)
at com.cube.zambezi.level.tile.Tile.<clinit>(Tile.java:15)
at com.cube.zambezi.level.Level.getTile(Level.java:95)
at com.cube.zambezi.level.Level.render(Level.java:71)
at com.cube.zambezi.Game.render(Game.java:172)
at com.cube.zambezi.Game.run(Game.java:142)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at com.cube.zambezi.graphics.SpriteSheet.load(SpriteSheet.java:34)
at com.cube.zambezi.graphics.SpriteSheet.<init>(SpriteSheet.java:29)
at com.cube.zambezi.graphics.SpriteSheet.<clinit>(SpriteSheet.java:19)
... 7 more
```

If you need more information, tell me.

Comment: Pls post relevant code snippet that caused this error. The exception says "input==null". Does that ring a bell to you ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read an image, but your input is null.

Make sure you have a valid input, either from a stream, a file or a URL, and the problem is solved.

If you don't know in advance, a simple `if (input != null)` around the `ImageIO.read` will fix it.

Comment: I'm assuming here that the `com.cube.zambezi` stuff is your own code.